# Left align text input onblur (IE 8 & 9)

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

I am looking for a method to left align the contents of a text input box when the user fires the onblur event. I have seen mention of solving the issue with onblur="this.value = this.value", but this does not work in IE.

To Clarify: This issue occurs in Internet Explorer when the user types beyond the width of the textbox and then leaves focus.  In Chrome and Firefox, the text will automatically left align, but this does not happen in IE.

Due to request, I've attached code (View in IE):

```
<input type="text" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3hjonneh/FZJjW/

Text Field:

[image: Text Field]

After Typing:

[image: After Typing]

After Blur:

[image: After Blur]

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

Comment: You mean you want the text to scroll back to its initial position?

Comment: @JuanMendes yes. That is the functionality that I am trying to capture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is rather a hack than a proper solution, but somehow it works:

```
function blurred(elem) {
    var range;
    // IE only, probably not the best check since it will run in other browsers
    // if they ever implement this feature
    if (elem.createTextRange) {
        range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.select();
    }
}

<input type="text" onchange="blurred(this);" />
```

Notice the use of `onchange` instead of `onblur`. This is since `select()` causes some troubles when using `onblur`.

Comment: Actually, why bother to change this feature at all? People who browse the web with IE, are used to it anyway.

Comment: But it does work http://jsfiddle.net/FtzjL/3/ You just need to fix it so it doesn't break in browsers that don't support `createTextRange`

Comment: @JuanMendes Fixed, but I'm not sure if it works in real IE8 & 9, I've only emulated those with IE10.

Comment: @JuanMendes OK. You tried also edit my post at the same time with me, I suppose I override your edits. If there's still something, feel free to edit it again : ).

Comment: This works but it causes problems with trying to gain focus on another input: http://jsfiddle.net/t3hjonneh/esP8F/4/  You will be unable to tab out of the first input.

Comment: @Jonneh There is a mention of using `onchange` instead of `onblur` in my answer, and also said `onblur` would cause harm. In your fiddle there's `onblur`.

Comment: @Teemu I took my fiddle from the one Juan posted; I'll change mine and confirm.

Comment: It's a decent solution, just won't work in the case where you only scrolled to the right, you may not have actually changed the value. However,  I tried a number of things (setting to blurred element focus, then blurring and restoring focus to the next element) to make it work with onblur and couldn't get it to work

Comment: @JuanMendes That's why I consider this being rather a hack : ). If the page isn't scrollable, you can use `onblur` & `range.scrollIntoView(true)`, but otherwise this causes some extra scrolling when page is scrolled offscreen before actual `blur` is triggered. A basic problem with `onblur` is, that to initialize the text, you'll need to focus to the `input` again, and that causes focus to stuck into `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery version I mocked up that works in all the major browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=text]').change(function(){
            try{//select nothing but side-effect is that text left justifies
                if(/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
                    return;//webkit browsers do it automatically
                } else if(this.createTextRange) { //ie
                    var r = this.createTextRange();
                    r.collapse(true);
                    r.select();
                } else if(typeof this.selectionStart !== "undefined") { //firefox
                    this.selectionStart = 0;
                    this.selectionEnd = 0;
                }
            } catch(err) {
            //?? nobody cares ??
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just set a class on that field and then fire up a function with the onBlur in your html: e.g. `onBlur="left()"` Then in your javascript you can then simply change the class with `.setAttribute` As an added bonus you can also set other properties for that class as well.

Although I do support the notion of posting relevant code

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this would help.  What css would you use in the class to force the text left? text-align: left; just causes very strange things to happen. And changing out the class itself doesn't cause the text to realign. There really isn't any code necessary to replicate this issue as a very basic input type=text element and internet explorer will produce the results.

Comment: @Jonneh Yes, if you want more people to help you, you do need to show code. Better yet, create a http://jsfiddle.net so people can play around. I don't even know what you mean by left aligning after a blur. FYI, I refuse to help on questions without code, the spirit of SO is here's my code, I expect it to do A, but it does B, how can I fix it?

Comment: @JuanMendes Its rather difficult to provide code for an issue that occurs without any really. However, I've attached screenshots to help clarify.

Comment: @Jonneh Teemu already figured it out, and I added a link to a working version. You should accept their answer. http://jsfiddle.net/FtzjL/3/ The pictures do clarify a lot though.

Comment: @JuanMendes The link you posted here is missing the fix. Thanks for your help.